# My product page layout configuration not responding to any changes?

Tags: product, layout, page

** I got changes in my product page layout and I want to restore it back to the default of my theme layout .. and the product configuration does not take any effect in changes of the col in the bootstrap system .. and there is pictures of my old and new layout that I want to change**

[image: THE CHANGES THAT OVERRIDE MY DEFAULT LAYOUT]

**THERE IS the OLD LAYOUT DEFAULTS THAT I WANT TO GET BACK TO IT**

[image]

**THATS THE DIFFERENTS BETWEEN THE OLD CONFIGURATIONS AND NEW ONE**

[image]

Comment: Clear cache and check it.

Comment: done clear cache and indexing too .. nothing happend .. the configration of the first picture can't be happend in the magento normal configration of the product page .. i blieve its extintions or something that does this change .. but i don't know it